# How to sum employee paychecks from multiple jobs into one table

Tags: sql, ms-access

table featuring fictitious employee data, area ( in hectares (ha)) cleared (noted in french as superficie), rate for 1 hectare of cleared land on the specific lot (french:taux) and amount due( expr1) for that lot.

[image]

My problem here is that I want the total amount due for each Worker, not the amount due for each worker for each lot. Totals for Sirs Alain, Jacques, Paul, Roger and Tanguay should normally be 4066, 4082 , 5638, 5811 and 3131 , respectively.

My code so far is this

```sql
SELECT tbl_Employés.Num_deb, tbl_Employés.Prénom, tbl_Employés.Nom, tbl_Employés.Age, tbl_Employés.DEP, tbl_Employés.Expérience, tbl_Employés.Adresse, Tbl_terrain.superficie, Tbl_terrain.Taux, [superficie]*[taux] AS [Montant à payer]
FROM tbl_Employés INNER JOIN Tbl_terrain ON tbl_Employés.Num_deb = Tbl_terrain.Num_deb
ORDER BY tbl_Employés.Nom;
```

I have so far tried to use GROUP BY Numéro_terrain, which returns an error that my query does not include the specified expression ''Num_deb'' as a part of an aggregation fuction

I woul greatly appreciate any imput. I am very sorry if you have a hard time understanding some words, as I am doing my best to translate everything from french.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to include all the columns in the `GROUP BY` that are not arguments to aggregation functions:

```
SELECT e.Num_deb, e.Prénom, e.Nom, e.Age, e.DEP, e.Expérience, e.Adresse, 
       SUM([superficie]*[taux]) AS [Montant à payer]
FROM tbl_Employés as e INNER JOIN
     Tbl_terrain as t
     ON e.Num_deb = t.Num_deb
GROUP BY e.Num_deb, e.Prénom, e.Nom, e.Age, e.DEP, e.Expérience, e.Adresse
ORDER BY e.Nom;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! This works indeed, but returns a table in which the field  ''Superficie'' is no longer present. I scratched my head a bit and simply added
 SUM ([superficie]) AS [superficie totale]
at the end of the ''SELECT'' line. 
(I should have mentionned that I also needed to return the value for total cleared area, but it was no big deal.)

Again, thank you so much for your help.